# Link archive to shared library with Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

Using Bazel, I'd like to link a position independent static archive directly to a shared library (not to the application using the shared library). Something like:

```
g++ -shared mylib.cpp archive.a -o libmylib.so
g++ mybin.cpp -lmylib -o mybin
```

Rationale: RedHat packages libelf as a static archive, that has some otherwise public symbols (e.g: `elf_errmsg`) marked as hidden: the archive must be linked to the module using it (in this case, the shared library): linking to the application is too late.

I tried:

- Wrapping the archive in a `cc_import` rule
- Adding the rule to the `deps` of the `cc_library`: doesn't work, archive gets linked to the app
- Adding the rule to the `srcs` of the `cc_library`: doesn't work, archive gets linked to the app
- Adding the archive file directly to the `linkopts` of the `cc_library`: almost works, but the archive gets linked to both the library *and* the binaries depending on it.
- Renaming the archive to `.lo` or `.pic.lo`: doesn't work, archive gets linked to the app with `-Wl,wholearchive`
- Adding `alwayslink = True` to the `cc_import`: doesn't work, archive gets linked to the app with `-Wl,wholearchive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work for what you're trying to do:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libmylib.so",
    srcs = ["mylib.cpp", "archive.a"],
    linkshared = True,
)

cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = ["libmylib.so"],
    hdrs = ["mylib.hpp"],
)
cc_binary(
    name = "mybin",
    srcs = ["mybin.cpp"],
    deps = [":mylib"],
)
```

You can build a shared library (which is done as `cc_binary(linkshared = True)`; this bit may not seem entirely intuitive) from your source and the library archive.

You can build a `cc_library` to use as a dependency of your other targets... and use that to build a `cc_binary` target.

In theory if this was just one time/place thing, you could probably shorten it like this (but it's more of a minimal length example):

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libmylib.so",
    srcs = ["mylib.cpp", "archive.a"],
    linkshared = True,
)

cc_binary(
    name = "mybin",
    srcs = ["mybin.cpp", "mylib.hpp", ":libmylib.so"],
)
```

Comment: Thanks. As also discussed on Bazel Slack, this seems to be the only option now. FTR, the shorter version makes unittesting the lib more difficult.