# How can i add external local library in my Bazel build?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv, bazel

I already have compiled OpenCV library which provides with OS in the box. I have header files in /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2, and their(maybe) implementation `.so` files in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu.

I want to add this OpenCV to my project, but I just can add headers without implementation via copts=["-I/usr/include/opencv4"] to my BUILD file.

Every time I got (in good way) this output when I tried to use:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0):
```

error: `undefined reference to 'cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int, int)'`

Can somebody help me with this problem?

I tried to add implementation via linkopts=["/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu"],

i tried to do that:

```
linkopts = [
    "-L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu",
    "-lopencv_videoio",
    "$(pkg-config --libs opencv)",
],
```

I tried to construct `cc_library` to add at least one file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "opencv_videoio",
    hdrs = glob(["/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/videoio.hpp"]),
    linkopts = [
        "-L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu",
        "-lopencv_videoio",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

But "Error in glob: pattern cannot be absolute"

All from this ways doesn't work.

I've found this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487115/link-archive-to-shared-library-with-bazel", but I already have my OpenCV and don't need to download another, so I don't understand completely how can I do this with my library.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/main/intermediate/cpp/OpenCVDemo