how do link eigen3 when compiling tensorflow?
While reading tensorflow source code, I found eigen3 folder only includes #include file as below. If not exist ".cpp" or other source code, I have a question: how do link corresponding functions and classes when compiling tensorflow?
// filename: eigen3/Eigen/Core
#include "Eigen/Core"


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487115/link-archive-to-shared-library-with-bazel

Suppose you have a target in the Tensorflow repo //foo:bar. Then in foo/BUILD you can do something like this:
cc_library(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = [
    # Your srcs here...
  ],
  # Other attrs...
  deps = [
    "//third_party/eigen3:eigen3", # or "//third_party/eigen3" for short
  ],
)

Bazel will handle the include paths and linking commands for you.
If your question is about which headers to use, you can find the list of headers in third_party/eigen3/BUILD. Eigen/Core has most of the definitions you'll need, but you can check out the Eigen3 docs to work out if you need any other includes.
